# Ajax-filling a dropdown to be triggered when previous dropdown doesn't change but has an option selected

Tags: jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have 3 dropdowns: the first one is filled from the server, the 2nd one is filled via ajax based on a change of the first one and the 3rd one also filled via ajax based on a change of the 2nd one.

This is the code for the 2nd or 3rd dropdown ajax:

```
$("select[name='myId']").change(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/getList",
    data: "id="+$("select[name='myId']").val(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $("select[name='nextId']").empty();
        $.each(data, function() { //Filling each option
            if(this.isSelected == 1) $("select[name='nextId']").append($("<option />").val(this.id).text(this.name).attr("selected","selected"));
            else $("select[name='nextId']").append($("<option />").val(this.id).text(this.name));
        });
    }
});
});
$("select[name='myId']").change();
```

As you can see I pass a "isSelected" parameter that pre-selects the value the user had selected in a previous submission of the form. The issue is that when a dropdown is prepopulated, it doesn't trigger a change event and therefore the next dropdown is not filled via ajax at all.

How can I trigger my ajax if the previous dropdown value changes (as it currently does) but also if the previous dropdown is not empty and a value is selected, and the current dropdown to fill is empty?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess `myId` is the first dropdown, `nextId` is the second, and you have an event handler attached to `nextId` which populates the third one?

Comment: yes, I should have explained: there is the same code for each dropdown except you replace myId by the dropdown that changes, and nextId by the one which must be populated. So there would be the same code twice, for when the 1st dropdown changes and for when the second dropdown changes. This will become a function in the future once I've ironed out all the kinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this in the success function, right after the `$.each()`:

```
if ( $("select[name='nextId'] option:selected").length ) {
    // an option is pre-selected
    // check if third dropdown is empty
    if ( $("select[name='nextNextId'] option").length == 0 ) {
        // third dropdown is empty
        // populate it by triggering change handler on second dropdown
        $("select[name='nextId']").change();
    }
}
```

This assumes the third dropdown is called nextNextId.